# Android logcat not showing error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I have a little problem, I used to be able to see everything in the logcat (I am using Android Studio), in particular when a Java error occured (e.g. NullPointerException) I could see it quite precisely in the logcat. However since a while, I can see my System.out.print, and my Log (i.e. Log.i, Log.d etc) for instance but not the errors...

Hence my app crashes and I have absolutely no clue why.

Anyone having the same issue?

Best,
Alex

Comment: did u specify filter key in the log box? if so remove it...

Comment: does switching to `Error` in the dropdown also doesnot work ?